# Alternatives for position absolute for responsive sites?

Tags: css, css-position

I'm practicing coding by making this, the only thing I'm having issues with is the small black bar with the arrows inside. I used position absolute but its doesn't work well since the site is responsive. What is a good alternative way to position this.

[image: Site with pictures of chairs]

[image: Site with pictures of chairs]

```css
/* Mobile First */

 :root {
  --DarkGrey: hsl(0, 0%, 63%);
  --Black: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --VeryDarkGray: hsl(0, 0%, 27%);
}

body {
  font-family: "League Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.homePage {
  position: relative;
}


/* The NavBar */

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

#logo {
  padding-left: 0.3125rem;
}

#hamburger {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.leftSide {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
  text-align: left;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.theLinks {
  height: 5.2rem;
  width: auto;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

#close {
  height: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.links {
  font-weight: 900;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}


/* The Body */

.theBody {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#mainDeskImage {
  display: none;
}

.leftRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15.7rem;
  left: 14.3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.header {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  color: var(--DarkGrey);
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

.shop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.shop .arrowimg {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollDescriptions {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.aboutHeader {
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.4rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: medium;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
}

.aboutDescription {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/* Fixing All of the images */

.images {
  width: 100%;
}


/* the left right arrows */

@media all and (min-width: 767px) {
  /* navbar */
  #hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  /* body */
  body {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  #topHalf {
    display: flex;
  }
  .aboutSection {
    display: flex;
  }
  #mainImage {
    display: none;
  }
  #mainDeskImage {
    display: flex;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .leftRight {
    display: none;
  }
  .scrollDescriptions {
    padding: 3.5rem;
  }
  #theSeats {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
  }
  #theChair {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .images .bottom {}
  .aboutDescription {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="homePage">
    <nav class="theNav" id="theNavbar">
      <div class="leftSide" id="theLeftSide">
        <img id="hamburger" src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="">
        <div class="thelogo">
          <img id="logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="theLinks" id="theLinksID">
        <img id="close" src="./images/icon-close.svg" alt="">
        <ul class="links">
          <li class="link">home</li>
          <li class="link">shop</li>
          <li class="link">about</li>
          <li class="link">contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="theBody">
      <div id="topHalf">
        <div id="changingImages">
          <img id="mainImage" class="images" src="./images/mobile-image-hero-1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="leftRight">
            <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-angle-left.svg" alt="">
            <img class="arrow" src="./images/icon-angle-right.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollDescriptions">
          <h2 class="header">Discover innovative ways to decorate</h3>
            <p class="description">We provide unmatched quality, comfort, and style for property owners across the country. Our experts combine form and function in bringing your vision to life. Create a room in your own style with our collection and make your property a reflection
              of you and what you love.
              <p class="shop">SHOP NOW
                <img class="arrowimg" src="./images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="">
              </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="aboutSection">
        <div class="darkImage">
          <img id="theSeats" class="images" src="./images/image-about-dark.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="aboutDescription">
          <h3 class="aboutHeader">ABOUT OUR FURNITURE</h3>
          <p class="description">Our multifunctional collection blends design and function to suit your individual taste. Make each room unique, or pick a cohesive theme that best express your interests and what inspires you. Find the furniture pieces you need, from traditional
            to contemporary styles or anything in between. Product specialists are available to help you create your dream space.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="lightImage">
          <img id="theChair" class="images" src="./images/image-about-light.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm using flexbox for the desktop layout part

Comment: Can you post your code as a [mre]? The use of a flexbox could be the solution to your problem.

Comment: `I used position absolute but its doesn't work well since the site is responsive. ` and what is the problem you are facing when using position `absolute`. While it is true that `absolute` is something you rarely use nowadays I don’t see why it would be a problem in this particular case.

Comment: If you want to place an element in the bottom right corner of an element using `absolute` then you want to use `right` and `bottom` for position and not `top` and `left`.

Answer (score 0):

### Position & Stacking Context

Position absolute positions the element in an absolute fashion, **relative to its closest positioned ancestor** with what is called a **stacking context**.

You can create this stacking context by setting the position to anything but static.

In short, try setting `#changingImages` to `position: relative`.

```css
#changingImages {
  position: relative;
}

.leftRight {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't test this because you didn't provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Let me know if it works, if not I'm happy to take another look when you provide one.

Comment: The code is listed in a snippet. That should be all you need. You can copy it over to another snippet, that's what I do.

Comment: @ethry Yes, I see, that snippet works great. And it wasn't when I created the comment.